# Shopify 2.0 how can I add multiple products to the cart?

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, shopify-api

I am currently working in Shopify's Sense theme and, in connection with that, I need to rewrite their Add To Cart function so that it can add more than one product to the cart at a time.

I have a setup where some additional products have been added to the product page, which the customer can add to a so-called bundle. When the customer clicks "add to cart" on the main product, it should add not only the main product but also the selected products in the bundle to the cart. Each bundle product has an associated form, just like the main product.

Here is Shopify's Add To Cart script:

```
onSubmitHandler(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  if (this.submitButton.getAttribute('aria-disabled') === 'true') return;

  this.handleErrorMessage();

  this.submitButton.setAttribute('aria-disabled', true);
  this.submitButton.classList.add('loading');
  this.querySelector('.loading-overlay__spinner').classList.remove('hidden');

  const config = fetchConfig('javascript');
  config.headers['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
  delete config.headers['Content-Type'];

  const formData = new FormData(this.form);
  if (this.cart) {
    formData.append('sections', this.cart.getSectionsToRender().map((section) => section.id));
    formData.append('sections_url', window.location.pathname);
    this.cart.setActiveElement(document.activeElement);
  }
  config.body = formData;
  console.log("Form data: " + formData);

  fetch(`${routes.cart_add_url}`, config)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status) {
        this.handleErrorMessage(response.description);

        const soldOutMessage = this.submitButton.querySelector('.sold-out-message');
        if (!soldOutMessage) return;
        this.submitButton.setAttribute('aria-disabled', true);
        this.submitButton.querySelector('span').classList.add('hidden');
        soldOutMessage.classList.remove('hidden');
        this.error = true;
        return;
      } else if (!this.cart) {
        window.location = window.routes.cart_url;
        return;
      }

      this.error = false;
      const quickAddModal = this.closest('quick-add-modal');
      if (quickAddModal) {
        document.body.addEventListener('modalClosed', () => {
          setTimeout(() => { this.cart.renderContents(response) });
        }, { once: true });
        quickAddModal.hide(true);
      } else {
        this.cart.renderContents(response);
      }
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(e);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      this.submitButton.classList.remove('loading');
      if (this.cart && this.cart.classList.contains('is-empty')) this.cart.classList.remove('is-empty');
      if (!this.error) this.submitButton.removeAttribute('aria-disabled');
      this.querySelector('.loading-overlay__spinner').classList.add('hidden');
    });
}
```

I imagine creating a forEach loop over each selected bundle product and creating a new formData for each one, then merging them all together with the main product's formData. However, I haven't been able to make it work completely.

You can read Shopify's Cart API Documentation on the subject here:

https://shopify.dev/docs/api/ajax/reference/cart

Please feel free to offer a potential solution or let me know what it would cost to have it done, especially if there's someone who can have it solved by today, Monday. :)